# Does `source` automatically follow symbolic links? - Bash

Tags: symlink, bash

I was wondering if `source ~/.bashrc` will work even when *~/.bashrc* is a symbolic link to a file located somewhere else?

Comment: Of course.

But the current directory remains `~`, which means that other profile files in the directory you're linking to are not visible by your script.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you! I'd be happy to accept this, if you post it as an answer. My current *.bash_profile* contains an around 10-lines long script to source *.bashrc* - even when *.bashrc* is a symlink. I think now I can just replace it with `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc fi`...

Comment: ....did you try this before asking?

Comment: @KyleStrand I did and it worked, but earlier I asked a question to write a script to follow a symbolic link and source the target. I was just expecting, that if there was a much more simpler way someone would've told me. Thus the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Bash tries to open the designated object, the filesystem follows the symbolic link on the `fopen` call.

But the current directory remains `~`, which means that other profile files in the directory you're linking to are not visible by the rc file pointed by the link.

So the interest is limited.

Also note that you should not test existence with `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc fi` because `-f` tests for *regular file*. You want `-e` flag (means: name points to something valid)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd say this is that limited, or why you'd expect the working directory to change. Symlinking rc files to "official" versions in a git clone is a really common technique, I think, and your shell rc files really shouldn't make assumptions about the working directory.

Comment: @KyleStrand: I was just saying that redirectling to a symlink does not make the current directory the directory of the symlink target, as some people may think. If you symlink, that mustn't be to "change directory".

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on macOS Sierra; I get `/Users/jes/.bashrc: No such file or directory` error. To get it to work, I have to cd into the directory where the "real" file is located.

Comment: are you sure your symlink destination is correct? absolute ? relative ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Darn! The symlink was fouled up; thanks for the push...